# Using Integers in SOQL For Loops - Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, cpulimit

I need to insert Monthly Revenue Forecast records for each Opportunity that's been inserted / updated, matches my criteria and caused the trigger to fire.

When I execute the below, in bulk via a test class, it causes an error

> System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

I've already changed the lines after `if(*list* size() > 0){` from `for(Opportunity o : insOpps){` to use the SOQL query's instead.

And my trigger's not updating any fields on the Opportunity - and therefore causing the trigger to fire again.

So I'm guessing that either I've got my syntax wrong (but I am closing each For loop and have the DLM statements outside the loops) or my use of integers with the SOQL for *loop* is causing the issue, could you please suggest potential causes?

```
trigger MRFv2 on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    List<WEID__c> weids = WEID__c.getall().values();
    Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

    // add Opportunity Record Type Ids from Custom Setting to list of valid Ids      
    for(WEID__c weid: weids) {
        try {
            validRecordTypeIds.add(weid.WEOppId__c);
        } catch (System.StringException e) {
            System.debug(
                System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                'Invalid Record Type Id ' + weid.WEOppId__c);
        }
    }

    List<Opportunity> insOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> upOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id,Integer> forecastDuration = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    Map<Integer,String> monthName = new Map<Integer,String>{1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December'};
    List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c> existMRFs = new List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c>();
    List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c> newMRFs = new List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> rampSett = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> rampTxnRev = new Map<Id,Decimal>();

    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New){

        if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId))
        {
            try{
                Opportunity oldO = Trigger.OldMap.get(o.Id);

                if(oldO.CloseDate != o.CloseDate
                   ||
                   oldO.Annual_Settlement_Value__c != o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Implementation_Revenue__c != o.Implementation_Revenue__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c != oldO.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c
                   ||
                   oldO.FSR_End_Date__c != o.FSR_End_Date__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c != o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Annual_transaction_volume__c != o.Annual_transaction_volume__c)
                {
                    upOpps.add(o);
                    forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));
                    system.debug('upOpps contains ' + upOpps);
                    system.debug('forecastDuration contains ' + forecastDuration);
                }
                //if old.Map is null, record has been inserted & MRF records should be added
            }catch(system.NullPointerException e){
                insOpps.add(o);
                forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));
            }
        }
    }

    if(insOpps.size() > 0){

        for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id,Name,Implementation_Revenue__c,Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c,
                                    Annual_Settlement_Value__c,Annual_transaction_volume__c,Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c,
                                    CurrencyIsoCode 
                               FROM Opportunity
                              WHERE Id IN :insOpps])
        {

            Date ic = o.Implementation_Revenue__c;
            Integer icm = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.month();//DELETE?

            //Ramp calculations
            Decimal increment = o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c / 100;
            Integer rDur = (1 / increment).setscale(0,roundingMode.DOWN).intValue();
            Integer fcstDuration = forecastDuration.get(o.Id);
            Decimal monthlySett = o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c / fcstDuration;
            Decimal annualTxnRev = o.Annual_transaction_volume__c*o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c;
            Decimal monthlyTxnRev = annualTxnRev/fcstDuration;

            //FSR calculations
            Integer fsrDur = forecastDuration.get(o.Id) - rDur;

            Decimal settLoopTotal = 0.00;
            Decimal txnrevLoopTotal = 0.00;

            //add Monthly Forecast records for 'ramp' months
            for(Integer m = 0; m < rDur; m++){

                Decimal ramp = increment*(m + 1);
                Decimal monthSett = monthlySett*ramp;
                Decimal monthTxnRev = monthlyTxnRev*ramp;

                Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                fm.Name = monthName.get(ic.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ ic.addMonths(m).year();
                fm.Revenue_Date__c = ic.addMonths(m + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
                fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = monthSett;
                fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = monthTxnRev;

                settLoopTotal = settLoopTotal + monthSett;
                txnrevLoopTotal = txnrevLoopTotal + monthTxnRev;

                newMRFs.add(fm);

                if(m == rDur - 1){
                    rampSett.put(o.Id,settLoopTotal);
                    rampTxnRev.put(o.Id,txnrevLoopTotal);
                    settLoopTotal = 0;
                    txnrevLoopTotal = 0;
                }
            }

            Decimal mnthlyFsrSett = (o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c - rampSett.get(o.Id)) / fsrDur;
            Decimal mnthlyFsrTxnRev = (annualTxnRev - rampTxnRev.get(o.Id)) / fsrDur;

            //add Monthly Forecast Records for rFSR Months
            for(Integer m = rDur; m < rDur + fsrDur; m++){

                Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                fm.Name = monthName.get(ic.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ ic.addMonths(m).year();
                fm.Revenue_Date__c = ic.addMonths(m + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
                fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = mnthlyFsrSett;
                fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = mnthlyFsrTxnRev;

                newMRFs.add(fm);
            }
        }
    }

    if(upOpps.size() > 0){

        for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id,
                            (SELECT Id FROM Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r) FROM Opportunity
                              WHERE Id IN :upOpps])
        {               

            if(o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r.size()> 0){
                existMRFs.addAll(o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r);
            }
        }
        delete existMRFs;

        for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id,Name,Implementation_Revenue__c,Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c,
                                    Annual_Settlement_Value__c,Annual_transaction_volume__c,Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c,
                                    CurrencyIsoCode 
                               FROM Opportunity
                              WHERE Id IN :upOpps])
        {

            Date ic = o.Implementation_Revenue__c;
            Integer icm = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.month();//DELETE?

            //Ramp calculations
            Decimal increment = o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c / 100;
            Integer rDur = (1 / increment).setscale(0,roundingMode.DOWN).intValue();
            Integer fcstDuration = forecastDuration.get(o.Id);
            Decimal monthlySett = o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c / fcstDuration;
            Decimal annualTxnRev = o.Annual_transaction_volume__c*o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c;
            Decimal monthlyTxnRev = annualTxnRev / fcstDuration;

            //FSR calculations
            Integer fsrDur = forecastDuration.get(o.Id) - rDur;

            Decimal settLoopTotal = 0.00;
            Decimal txnrevLoopTotal = 0.00;

            //add Monthly Forecast records for 'ramp' months
            for(Integer m = 0; m < rDur; m++){

                Decimal ramp = increment*(m + 1);
                Decimal monthSett = monthlySett*ramp;
                Decimal monthTxnRev = monthlyTxnRev*ramp;

                Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                fm.Name = monthName.get(ic.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ ic.addMonths(m).year();
                fm.Revenue_Date__c = ic.addMonths(m + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
                fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = monthSett;
                fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = monthTxnRev;

                settLoopTotal = settLoopTotal + monthSett;
                txnrevLoopTotal = txnrevLoopTotal + monthTxnRev;

                newMRFs.add(fm);

                if(m == rDur - 1){
                    rampSett.put(o.Id,settLoopTotal);
                    rampTxnRev.put(o.Id,txnrevLoopTotal);
                    settLoopTotal = 0;
                    txnrevLoopTotal = 0;
                }
            }

            Decimal mnthlyFsrSett = (o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c - rampSett.get(o.Id)) / fsrDur;
            Decimal mnthlyFsrTxnRev = (annualTxnRev - rampTxnRev.get(o.Id)) / fsrDur;

            //add Monthly Forecast Records for rFSR Months
            for(Integer m = rDur; m < rDur + fsrDur; m++){

                Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                fm.Name = monthName.get(ic.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ ic.addMonths(m).year();
                fm.Revenue_Date__c = ic.addMonths(m + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
                fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = mnthlyFsrSett;
                fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = mnthlyFsrTxnRev;

                //if test for empty list?
                newMRFs.add(fm);
            }
        }
    }
    insert newMRFS;
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I reduce the number of records which are inserted / updated in my test Class, a different error message is displayed

> Too many DML rows: 10001

**UPDATE**

I've now isolated the cause of the DML row issue to the second inner loop for the section of my code that starts `if(upOpps.size() > 0){`. If I comment out the section, see below, the trigger passes my test successfully.

```
            Decimal mnthlyFsrSett = (o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c - rampSett.get(o.Id)) / fsrDur;
            Decimal mnthlyFsrTxnRev = (annualTxnRev - rampTxnRev.get(o.Id)) / fsrDur;

            //add Monthly Forecast Records for rFSR Months
          /*  For(Integer m = rDur; m < rDur + fsrDur; m++){

                Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                fm.Name = monthName.get(ic.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ ic.addMonths(m).year();
                fm.Revenue_Date__c = ic.addMonths(m + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
                fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = mnthlyFsrSett;
                fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = mnthlyFsrTxnRev;

                //if test for empty list?
                newMRFs.add(fm);
            }*/
        }
    }
    insert newMRFS;
}
```

This is pretty odd as the inner loop is a copy from the `if(insOpps.size() > 0){` section, which does have code coverage.

The size of the upOpps list is 0, if I add the debug line just before or just after `if(upOpps.size() > 0){` whereas insOpps size is 200.

But my test class inserts the 200 Opportunities and then does update them - I have code coverage for the lines after the upOpps size if test.

**Test Class**

```
        //create Opportunitys to update, in bulk
    List<Opportunity> opportunitys = new List<Opportunity>();

    for (Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

        Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
        o.name = 'Test Opp' + i;
        o.RecordTypeId = '012700000005qif';
        o.OwnerId = u.Id;

        o.StageName = '1) Suspect';
        o.CloseDate = date.newInstance(2015,06,15);
        o.Implementation_Revenue__c = date.newInstance(2015, 08, 15);
        o.FSR_End_Date__c = date.newInstance(2016, 08, 15);
        o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 40;

        //cover Forecast validation rules
        o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c = 0;
        o.Annual_transaction_volume__c = 0;

        //cover Credit Agreement Details Required validation rule
        o.Credit_Limit__c = 100.00;
        o.Date_Credit_Limit_Approved__c = date.newInstance(1901, 01, 01);
        o.Payment_Terms_Days__c = 5;
        o.Billing_Cycle__c = 'Daily';

        //cover Revenue Values Required validation rule
        o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c = 100.00;
        o.Average_transaction_Value_POS__c = 1.00;

        opportunitys.add(o);
    }
    insert opportunitys;
    system.debug('opportunitys contains ' + opportunitys);

    for(Opportunity upOppsDate : opportunitys){
        upOppsDate.CloseDate = date.newInstance(2015,07,15);
    }
    update opportunitys;
```

Comment: I've experienced this limit when using the Math class, which eats up CPU.   Have you considered using Flows, pre-calculating,  or using Custom field formulas to reference?  Does this happen with 20 or 200 records?

Comment: @James I could use custom formula fields..but there might be another cause of the issue - when I reduce the number of records in the test to 20, I get a different error 'Too many DML rows: 10001' so I must have included a DML statement in a loop but I can't see where - could this be linked to using the SOQL query to find the Opportunities to relate the MRF records to?

Comment: I would like at using batch apex to handle the Too many DML rows: 10001 error: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: @AlexS, i recommend putting debug logs to include the size of all Lists and work with 1 record to test the scale ( if 1 record creates 100 new records, you'll definitely hit issues.   I suspect a list is loaded with too manay rows, so find a way to reduce this and make even more efficient.  as Girbot mentioned, should you require more than 10K DML rows, you'll need to leverage batch APEX.

Comment: @Girbot thanks for the suggestion, the test definitely isn't supposed to create 10,001 records so something else is causing the issue.

Comment: @James thanks for the suggestion, I'm working on the size debugging now.

Comment: @AlexS, any update on how many records each list is populated with before running calcs?

Comment: @James even with the increased log memory at 5mb, the log size is still too large, to show me the debug logs with the size of the lists! I've asked Salesforce support to help me spot the section of the code that's creating all of the DML rows, I expect that this is also the cause of the CPU time limit being exceeded.

Comment: @James I've made some progress now, in terms of isolating the cause of the issue and updated my question with the details, if you're able to take a look?

Comment: @AlexS, given you are working with a standard set of records (~200), what I suspect is your trigger must be re-processing somewhere.     Have you used Trigger Context variables?   The one of interest would be **Trigger.IsExecuting** in one of your IF blocks, which will check whether your trigger was invoked by a trigger -- ending the loop.     Here's more detail regarding Trigger Context Variables: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

Comment: @James that sounds great so is there a way to use the context variable with my existing Trigger or do I have to use a controller Class (which I'm keen to avoid - because I've never had to write an Apex Class before), like the one shown in [this post](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/prevent-an-apex-trigger-from-executing-twice.html)? I am already using isInsert & isUpdate in this trigger by the way, in place of my Try & Catch at the beginning, if that helps..

Comment: Here's an example:  If(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.IsExecuting){//your code here}

Comment: @James thanks, I thought you had it there but adding `Trigger.IsExecuting` for both the insOpps & upOpps If checks (& therefore exiting the code if isExecuting is false), following your example, hasn't worked. If the trigger is causing the loop won't the context always be isExecuting though?

Comment: What is the maximum duration (months) that would be generated for an Opp?  Are you sytem.debugging to see what values are generated.   Somewhere, I don't know where, you are processing/generating too many records,

Comment: @James so 12 records are being inserted / updated per opportunity & I'm creating 200 Opportunities. I've now found a [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004825&language=en_US) which says that the limit is really 100 rows. I'm inserting 2,400 records, in one DML statement. My Insert is outside the loop but could this still cause me to hit the governor limit?

Comment: @James in fact if I edit my test class to only create & update 150 Opportunities, I don't hit the error. So it's somewhere between 150 & 200 that I have the problem..I don't understand what the Knowledge Article means by a 'collection object' though, do you know by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code. So many that I don't want to go into detail with them all. First is that it would be very helpful to you to separate your initial test for data into an

```
If(Trigger.isInsert)
{
   for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New)
   {
      forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));

   {

    upOpps.addAll(trigger.new);
{ 

// there's nothing in trigger.old to test against, so no need in AfterInsert

If(Trigger.isUpdate)
{
   for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New)
   {

       // record selection code here
   {

{

Opportunity oldO = Trigger.OldMap.get(o.Id);
```

For you selection criteria in AfterUpdate:

```
// try{
//              Opportunity oldO = Trigger.OldMap.get(o.Id);
```

You don't want to use a try-catch block in your trigger. This is cpu intensive. With separate blocks, this is not necessary. Test it and see. If fields aren't required or validated, do a null test instead.

```
// record selection code 

for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New)
{
   if(oldO.CloseDate != o.CloseDate
      ||
      oldO.Annual_Settlement_Value__c != o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c
      ||
      oldO.Implementation_Revenue__c != o.Implementation_Revenue__c
      ||
      oldO.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c != oldO.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c
      ||
      oldO.FSR_End_Date__c != o.FSR_End_Date__c
      ||
      oldO.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c != o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c
      ||
      oldO.Annual_transaction_volume__c != o.Annual_transaction_volume__c)
      {
      upOpps.add(o);
      forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));

{
```

This is SIX OR conditions to test at the same time. It *might* behoove you to break these up into 6 If conditions where you add the ID's to a set. Once you have them, at the end, add all of them to a single set. Let's call it `OupIds` for our purposes.

You can convert `OupIds` to a list from trigger.newmap to get your list of opportunities and create your map for the oppIds that are in the set should you need to. I suspect that a test will show that doing it this way will prove faster, but don't have comparable data at the moment I can test with to prove one way or another. I can only guarantee that it will be faster than repeating the try-catch that you're using.

```
for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id,Name,Implementation_Revenue__c,Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c,
                                    Annual_Settlement_Value__c,Annual_transaction_volume__c,Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c,
                                    CurrencyIsoCode 
                               FROM Opportunity
                              WHERE Id IN :insOpps])
        {
```

You don't need to run this query. You will already have all of this info. It should be contained in trigger.new or trigger.newmap for the Ids that you've determined need to be processed.

I would run the following loop on `OupIds`, not on the object and pull the data from trigger.newmap.

```
For(Id oid:OupIds)
{

   Date ic = trigger.newmap.get(oid).Implementation_Revenue__c;
   Integer icm = trigger.newmap.get(oid).Implementation_Revenue__c.month();//DELETE?

   //Ramp calculations
   Decimal increment = trigger.newmap.get(oid).Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c / 100;

   // You're inside of a loop, don't define each of these variables each time through!!! 
   // Initialize them once and only once outside the loop instead

   Integer rDur = (1 / increment).setscale(0,roundingMode.DOWN).intValue();
   Integer fcstDuration = forecastDuration.get(oid);
   Decimal monthlySett = trigger.newmap.get(oid).Annual_Settlement_Value__c / fcstDuration;
   Decimal annualTxnRev = trigger.newmap.get(oid)..Annual_transaction_volume__c*trigger.newmap.get(oid).Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c;
   Decimal monthlyTxnRev = annualTxnRev/fcstDuration;

   //FSR calculations
   Integer fsrDur = forecastDuration.get(oId) - rDur;

   Decimal settLoopTotal = 0.00;
   Decimal txnrevLoopTotal = 0.00;

   //add Monthly Forecast records for 'ramp' months
   for(Integer m = 0; m < rDur; m++){

   Decimal ramp = increment*(m + 1);
   Decimal monthSett = monthlySett*ramp;
   Decimal monthTxnRev = monthlyTxnRev*ramp;

   // ### same comments here on these variables, you're recreating them within an inner loop!!!

   Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
   fm.Opportunity__c = oId;
   fm.CurrencyIsoCode = trigger.newmap.get(oid).CurrencyIsoCode;
   fm.Name = monthName.get(ic.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ ic.addMonths(m).year();
   fm.Revenue_Date__c = ic.addMonths(m + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
   fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = monthSett;
   fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = monthTxnRev;

   settLoopTotal = settLoopTotal + monthSett;
   txnrevLoopTotal = txnrevLoopTotal + monthTxnRev;

   newMRFs.add(fm);

   if(m == rDur - 1){
      rampSett.put(oid,settLoopTotal);
      rampTxnRev.put(oid,txnrevLoopTotal);
      settLoopTotal = 0;
      txnrevLoopTotal = 0;
   }
}
```

I'm certain you can see where these comments would apply to the remaining portions of your code.

Comment: Thanks so just to clarify, you think it's mainly the calculations inside the loop which are causing the issue? Do I need to store each 'calculation' (the decimals, integers etc.) in a map, with their Opportunity Id so that I can reference the from the Integer loops or..?

Comment: First, I was responding to the CPU time limit exceeded and either you hadn't updated with the "too many DML", or I didn't see it. Off hand, I'm not seeing where you're repeatedly accessing the same values between inner and outer loops. Feel free to point them out to me. If there's someplace you're repeating the same calculation on same numbers in the outer loop again in the inner loop, then obviously a map would be beneficial. And I think it's a combination of selections, declarations and calculations, but more declarations & calculations.

Comment: It's the same calculation but different numbers each time so if I need to do those calculations outside the loops, I think I need somewhere to store the results (whereas obviously they're populating the fields of the MRF records immediately at the moment), what would you recommend? I'll come back to you about accessing the same values in the inner & outer loops, I should be able to work out how to manage that.

Comment: If different numbers each time and you're writing them to a `list<object>`, no need to put in a separate map unless `map<id,object>` since you can access the current state of the object from the loop. Just use that instance of the `list<object>` or `map<id,object>` to retrieve values as needed. You don't want to duplicate effort if you're exceeding cpu time and it's already in memory. If not writing directly to object or map of object, then separate maps would make sense if you need it later.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that I can't write the results of the calculations to an object - unless they're populating a field? So I'll use maps i.e. `map<id,integer>` to store variable `icm` for example. Just wanted to check that I'm not missing anything there.

Comment: That's correct. Unless populating a field, you'd want to create a map for it. With `icm`, are you talking about `Integer icm = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.month();`? (I'm not as familiar with your code as you are) You could map it by month if you wanted to. That said, it should be a quick calculation/retrieval if you recalc directly using entire formula since it's an integer rather than a floating point as floats take more processing time than ints. You'd definitely want a map for it if you plan to reuse it outside your inner loop.